# UNITY_EDITOR undefined in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging some code from within the Unity editor that starts with `#if UNITY_EDITOR`, but UNITY_EDITOR isn't getting defined though I'm running Visual Studio through the Unity editor. I've tried

- Ensuring that I've got Visual Studio set in Debug mode (vs. Release)
- The Scripting Define Symbols settings, and msc and csc solutions from here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html?_ga=2.148389495.1394951635.1638832224-1796620461.1636419298

I've also tried to just add a #define to the project sheets that Unity is generating, which doesn't work because there's no project files that these files are being opened & debugged through. And, I've regenerated solution files. What am I missing? Thank you!

**Edit:**

Some additional important information: this behavior isn't happening in all files within the Visual Studio instance, just files that are NOT included inside of any of the the .csproj's in the solution I have open. So, my workspace is .csproj's that *do* have UNITY_EDITOR defined, but the file I'm opening is from outside of that project. In this case, the .cs file I'm trying to debug into is from a package that is running, so the debugger will drop into it, but no .csproj is generated for this package.

It seems to me that there should be different behavior here, but I'm not sure what it is. Should Unity create a .csproj for packages whose .cs files you can debug into so that you can view them correctly in Visual Studio?

So, finally: in the context of the existing .csproj's that I have open, if I add a line `<Compile Include="Full\Path\To\File.cs" />`, it works as desired. Kludgy, but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the existing .csproj's that I have open, if I add a line , it works as desired. Kludgy, but it works for my purposes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).